# SQLite is not updating the record in Table - Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite

I'm trying to update the value in table. I'm executing the following query of update to update particular record. Query is executing fine but its not updating the record. I have checked database is in document directory and database opening is successfull. Don't know where is the error. why table is not getting updated.

```
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES );
        NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *fullPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"agpla.sqlite"];


        sqlite3_stmt *updateStmt;
        const char *dbpath = [fullPath UTF8String];
        if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            const char *sql = "UPDATE favorites SET Crop = ?, Seeds = ?, Width = ? Where id=?";
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &updateStmt, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
                sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 4, [titleLabel.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
               // sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 1, [seedsField.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                //sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 2, [rowField.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
                 sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 1, [seedsField.text intValue]);
                 sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 2, [rowField.text intValue]);
               sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 3, [appDel.idToDelete intValue]);
            }
        }
        if(sqlite3_step(updateStmt) != SQLITE_DONE) {
            NSLog(@"Problems updating entry in reminder");
        }

        /* Finished */
        sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt);
```

Comment: FYI - you should be calling `sqlite3_step` and `sqlite3_finalize` inside the `if (sqlite3_prepare_v2...)` block. And you should be calling `sqlite3_close` at the end of the `if (sqlite3_open...)` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues here. But the primary seems to be that the value you bind to the `id` in the `where` clause doesn't match any existing records. Keep in mind that `Crop` is bind index 1, `Seeds` is index 2, `Width` is index 3, and `id` is index 4.

Here's a clean version of your code:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES );
NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"agpla.sqlite"];


sqlite3_stmt *updateStmt;
const char *dbpath = [fullPath UTF8String];
if(sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *sql = "UPDATE favorites SET Crop = ?, Seeds = ?, Width = ? Where id=?";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &updateStmt, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 1, [titleLabel.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 2, [seedsField.text intValue]);
        sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 3, [rowField.text intValue]);
        sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 4, [appDel.idToDelete intValue]);

        if(sqlite3_step(updateStmt) != SQLITE_DONE) {
            NSLog(@"Problems updating entry in reminder");
        }

        /* Finished */
        sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt);
    }

    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Comment: yes agreed. That was the only reason. 
 Crop is bind index 1, Seeds is index 2, Width is index 3, and id is index 4.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it working now :)
 My indexing was wrong. 
 Crop is bind index 1, Seeds is index 2, Width is index 3, and id is index 4.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,        NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"agpla.sqlite"];
        //NSString *filePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Accounts.sqlite"];
       // sqlite3 *database;
        sqlite3_stmt *updateStmt;
        if(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            const char *sql = "update favorites Set Seeds = ?, Width = ?  Where ID = ?";
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &updateStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
                NSLog(@"Error while creating update statement. %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
        sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 1, [seedsField.text intValue]);
        sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 2, [rowField.text intValue]);
        sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 3 , [appDel.idToDelete intValue]);


        char* errmsg;
        sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT", NULL, NULL, &errmsg);

        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt))
            NSLog(@"Error while updating. %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt);


        sqlite3_close(database);
```

Comment: You should probably explain what the problem was, and how you corrected it.

Comment: yeah . My indexing was wrong. 
 Crop is bind index 1, Seeds is index 2, Width is index 3, and id is index 4.

Answer (score -1):

In Swift 3.1

```
   var paths: [Any] = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
var documentsPath: String? = (paths[0] as? String)
var filePath: String = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath!).appendingPathComponent("agpla.sqlite").absoluteString
    //NSString *filePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Accounts.sqlite"];
    // sqlite3 *database;
var updateStmt: sqlite3_stmt?
if sqlite3_open(filePath.utf8, database) == SQLITE_OK {
    let sql = "update favorites Set Seeds = ?, Width = ?  Where ID = ?"
    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, updateStmt, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
        print("Error while creating update statement. \(sqlite3_errmsg(database))")
    }
}
sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 1, CInt(seedsField.text))
sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 2, CInt(rowField.text))
sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 3, CInt(appDel.idToDelete))
var errmsg = [CChar]()
sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT", nil, nil, errmsg)
if SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt) {
    print("Error while updating. \(sqlite3_errmsg(database))")
}
sqlite3_finalize(updateStmt)
sqlite3_close(database)
```